# The document “ViewController.swift” could not be saved. The file doesn’t exist

Tags: ios, xcode

When I move `ViewController.swift` file another group X-code show popup and I click re-save. after all when I try to close my project Xcode show this message `The document “ViewController.swift” could not be saved. The file doesn’t exist.`

Comment: every time when I try to run my project I get a message `The document “ViewController.swift” could not be saved. The file doesn’t exist.`

Comment: How do you move that file? Drag and drop direct in Xcode or just in Finder? If in Finder, you must remove the old link to this file and re-add again in new location

Comment: I move that file drag and drop direct in Xcode

Answer (score 14):

This happens quite often when moving files around.

What I do:

- Locate the file in your project folder and drag to desktop
- In xcode delete the file
- Close Xcode, you may have to force quit if it keeps showing the `The document “ViewController.swift” could not be saved. The file doesn’t exist.` alert.
- Reopen xcode and drag the file from your desktop to the folder in
  xcode project where you want it to be.
- Build and the message should have gone.

Comment: This just happened to me with a storyboard file. I followed these instructions and they worked, with one additional step of going to Targets/Build Phases/Copy Bundle Resources and deleted the storyboard file there as well.

Comment: I just restart XCode and it worked

Comment: I read @mohsen's comment after doing this, but yes, this seems to have done the trick. Not sure yet about git/source control but the files do seem to retain the git flag "R" in my case, next to the file name in the XCode navigation panel, after I re-create the folder and files it was complaining about.  Hopefully it's just XCode's state that got out of whack and not git's.  I did notice when XCode was restarted (after Force Quit) that it alluded to using data found on disk, so I guess that's the time when XCode realizes it has some broken references and decides to let reality speak for itself.

Answer (score 0):

Make a zip of that project and delete the original project. After that force quit the system. Then start the system again and unzip the zipped project.
Thank-You

Comment: seems a tad drastic

Answer (score 0):

This issue occurred to me when I tried to move an xib file to a group.
I reverted my work and still the error occurred although the project was running normally.

I switched to a different git branch and ran my code it ran normally with no error message, then I returned to my branch again and ran the project and the error message disappeared.